# Debugging a dynamically-loaded library with gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, gdb, dynamic-library

I am trying to debug an application which loads dynamic libraries as plugins, and experiencing problems with gdb to locate the source files and put breakpoints at the source level.

I build a dynamic library (`libFoo.so`) which is compiled with a static library  (`libBar.a`).

After building libFoo.so, it is moved in the plugins directory of my main application, which lives in a different folder.

At run-time the application starts and looks up this directory, then loads libFoo.so. All code is built with debug info, and the debug info is correctly loaded for the dynamic library.

What puzzles me is that source code information is not loaded in gdb for libFoo.Which means that when code breaks into a function of libFoo, I can't see the source code with `list` or set breakpoints.

However, source code information from libBar (which is linked statically in libFoo.so) is perfectly loaded and I can see source when breaking into code from libBar and put breakpoints in code from libBar...

To be more precise here's what gdb shows me about shared libraries:

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary Foo
From   To     Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x...  0x...  Yes         /path/to/mainapp/plugins/libFoo.so
```

OK, so my lib is loaded with debug symbols.

```
(gdb) info sources
Source files for which symbols have been read in:
... 
/path/to/mainapp/src/main.cpp
/path/to/plugins/libs/bar/bar.cpp
...
```

So, gdb has correctly loaded source code from `libBar.a` even if it lives in a different folder than the executable, but not from libFoo which was built along with it ?

I also tried to add the source directory of `libFoo` with `dir` in gdb, to no avail.

Where can I look at to help gdb make the link between libFoo and its source ?
Can I specify the source files explicitly (and not just the directory with `dir`) ? Or is there some option I am missing ?

Comment: I'm curious, can you build a minimal complete example? I could not reproduce this however hard I tried. gdb always finds the source, as long as it has not been moved.

Comment: I tried a minimal repro case and it works too... so back to square one...

Comment: I can only guess that your build is set-up to run gcc from a temporary directory or do some other weird things. You can look inside your .so file with `objdump -sj .debug_info libFoo.so` and see some directory names side by side with your source file names. If you don't see them then you are probably not using the right debug options (`-ggdb` or whatever).

Comment: You were right. It was a cmake config problem...

Comment: @Louen You should write an answer so the next person that has this problem can figure out what is wrong.